# Is the first Open Mic Nite open in the Auditorium?

Tags: discussion, chat, event

Is the Open Mic Nite happening right now?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** The first Open Mic Nite has ended. Next one will be Wednesday, March 16 2022.

*Earlier:*

Yes. In order to catch some kind of "nighttime" for participants all over the world it will run for 24 hours:

**Tuesday, March 1, 5:00pm UTC — Wednesday, March 2, 5:00pm UTC**

To post a submission to the Open Mic Nite, please visit [the Auditorium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126233/the-auditorium) and post a link to your piece of music prefixed with the text "`Open Mic:` ".

Rock On!